# Constantly get direction of mouse using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mousemove

I am trying to implement my own scrolling in a ticker with Jquery because the normal scrolling doesn't work too well when it's countering animation. I need to detect the direction that the mouse is moving in. I can constantly get the mouse's current position, what I need to do is save that current position, and then save it for the next check. How can I save `event.clientX` for the next move?

The code I am working with is line 24-37 in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/easilyBaffled/dLe3p/12/):

```
function track_mouse_pos(event) {
    var direction = "right";
    if(event.clientX < event.data.start_x){
       direction = "left"; 
    }
    $('#start_mouse_tracker').html("( " + direction + " )");
    $('#drag_tracker').html("( " + event.clientX + ", " + event.clientY + " )");
}

$("#controller").mousedown(function (event) {
    var start_x = event.clientX;
    var start_y = event.clientY;
    $("#controller").on('mousemove', {start_x: start_x}, track_mouse_pos);
});
```

**EDIT**
It's worth noting that I have tried to save the value in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/easilyBaffled/dLe3p/11/)
I added this to the if statement, but it still didn't fix the problem, so the question I guess should be, where should I save the current mouse position? Should it be a global variable or is there something in the mousemove event I can use?

```
var current_x = event.data.start_x
    if(event.clientX < current_x){
       direction = "left"; 
       current_x = event.clientX;
    }
    else{
        direction = "right"; 
       current_x = event.clientX;
    }
```

Comment: You already have the information in variables, perhaps push to an array? You could do it in the callback of on()

Comment: @JayBlanchard An array would get huge, fast. You only need to store the most recent mouse position and compare it to the current one to compute direction.

Comment: True @Blazemonger. You could also push and pop to keep the array a certain size.

Comment: Btw, you absolutely do not want to create a new event inside the `mousedown` event.